# Android Camera Orientation setting Exif on ActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera, orientation, android-camera-intent

I know its been asked many times but looking through all the questions I still can't figure it out.

Basically I'm capturing an image which is fine but I'm trying to work out what orientation it was actually taken in. I know we can set Exif properties and i've done that but the problem lies between taking the picture and accepting the picture for activity result.

So for example a user will the start the camera and its in portrait mode. User will then rotate the device to go landscape. They take the picture. The preview comes up. They rotate back to portrait then click OK to accept the picture.

After OK it will go to activityresult where i set the Exif orientation but its incorrect because when I check orientation in activityresult its at portrait whereas the picture was actually taken in landscape.

Hope that all makes sense.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "where i set the Exif orientation" -- why are you trying to do this? For most devices that I have tested, the camera firmware sets this header, or it rotates the image properly (so the header is not needed).

Comment: `I know we can set Exif properties`. Why would you 'set' an orientation? You should 'get' the orientation of the image in the .jpg file using the exif header of the file. Please show your onActivityResult code. It seems that you do wrong things there.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, you're both right, i tested the exif orientation and its set by the camera. Not sure why I put the set exif code in, thinking back I think i did have an old tablet with cyanogenmod which was my first test tablet before I bought this Samsung one, I think that was the reason as orientation wasn't being set. Either ways thanks both, i was doing something that i didn't need to do!

Comment: As CommonsWare was first how do I accept yours as the answer?